# Install sshfs on Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03

Tags: amazon-ec2, sshfs

SSHFS does not seem to be in the repository of the Amazon Linux AMI 2012.03.

So I tried from Source:

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/fuse/fuse-2.X/2.9.1/fuse-2.9.1.tar.gz
tar xvzf fuse-2.9.1.tar.gz
cd fuse-2.9.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

But after that I still get `-bash: sshfs: command not found`

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sshfs` is not part of the `fuse` code. Please consult the [homepage](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) first, before trying to build stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was to tired... On this page http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse/files/sshfs-fuse/ I read that "Looking for the latest version? Download fuse-2.9.1.tar.gz (559.7 kB)" So I thought I was downloading sshfs ...

Comment: answer did not help. how to install sshfs on aws linux still unclear.

Answer (score 0):

From [this AWS article](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/):

> ### Amazon Linux
>
> ##### Amazon Linux 2:
>
> Install the EPEL release package for RHEL 7 and enable the EPEL
> repository.
>
> ```
> sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
> ```
>
> ##### Amazon Linux Amazon Machine Image (AMI):
>
> The EPEL repository is already installed on the original version of
> Amazon Linux, but you must enable it. You can enable this repository
> either by using the yum-config-manager command or by editing the
> epel.repo file.
>
> ```
> sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel
> ```

Install `sshfs`:

```
sudo yum install sshfs
```